# To point domain to IP address with port number (ubuntu)

Tags: networking, dns

I have my domain on namecheap and My ubuntu server on upcloud. My react app is installed on ubuntu server. It's ip is xx.xx.xx.xx:3000 I tried pointing it through namecheap but when I go to the url it shows the content from xx.xx.xx.xx (not from xx.xx.xx.xx:3000) How to solve this issue?

Comment: DNS only does addresses, not port numbers.

Comment: @RonMaupin how to solve it?

Comment: You do not. Also, this is not a programming question. You could try to ask on [sf].